# Make some controls visible when screen layout breakpoint is reached - UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have 2 images and 5 buttons in between those 2 images in header of UI5 application. On using Overflowtoolbar, the overflow (...) is shown at the extreme right, how can I make it appear in between exactly considering I will adjust the overflow priority as "Never overflow" for both the images and they will never overflow. 
Another way: Is it possible to introduce an action sheet/ breadcrumb menu in the header and make it visible only if certain screen breakpoint is reached and at that time make all the other buttons disappear. In a way - to make certain controls visible/hide based on breakpoint level.

Goal is to have both the images visible till the point its possible and rest everythig in ... preferably in between those images. Else I am not seeing those ..., only 2 images are shown in small screen.

***XML.view***

```
    <OverflowToolbar design="Transparent">

    <Image src="images/abc.png" height="3.5rem">
            <layoutData>
            <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="High"/>
        </layoutData>
        </Image>
    <Button id="1">
        <layoutData>
            <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low"/>
        </layoutData>
    </Button>
    <Button id="2">
        <layoutData>
            <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low"/>
        </layoutData>
    </Button>
    <Button id="3">
        <layoutData>
            <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low"/>
        </layoutData>
    </Button>
    <Button id="4">
        <layoutData>
            <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low"/>
        </layoutData>
    </Button>
    <Button id="5">
        <layoutData>
            <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low"/>
        </layoutData>
    </Button>
    <ToolbarSpacer></ToolbarSpacer>
    <Image src="images/logo.png" height="2rem">
            <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow"/>
        </layoutData>
    </Image>
    <ToolbarSeparator></ToolbarSeparator>
    <core:Icon id="loginInfo" src="sap-icon://customer" size="2rem"/>
</OverflowToolbar>
```

Comment: _> Is it possible to introduce an action sheet/ breadcrumb menu_ ... Do you mean something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvFox.png

Comment: Yes something like that. Thank you. Could you please share some code base for same?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57102869/5846045

Comment: The `<ToolbarLayoutData shrinkable="true" />` is no longer needed since SAPUI5/OpenUI5 1.103.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of *two images with an action sheet / breadcrumb menu in between:*

```xml
<OverflowToolbar asyncMode="true">
  <Image src="..." />
  <Breadcrumbs currentLocationText="Laptop">
    <layoutData>
      <ToolbarLayoutData shrinkable="true" /><!-- if UI5 version < 1.103. -->
      <!-- Note: sap.m.Breadcrumbs is shrinkable by default since UI5 1.103. -->
    </layoutData>
    <links>
      <!-- ... -->
    </links>
  </Breadcrumbs>
  <Image src="..." />
</OverflowToolbar>
```

[image: ui5 overflowtoolbar with shrinkable breadcrumbs]
<sup>From https://jsbin.com/humuxew/edit?js,output</sup>

In order to make breadcrumbs shrinkable in the toolbar, `<ToolbarLayoutData shrinkable="true"/>` needs to be added to the `layoutData` aggregation.*

---

* **Update:** unless the SAPUI5/OpenUI5 version ≥ 1.103 (See [commit: `512d3dd`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/512d3dd3573ee00e918a4ccc610329058fd47236)).

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to solve your task with an OverflowToolbar since the ... are always rendered as last element (see [Renderer: Line 23](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/OverflowToolbarRenderer.js)).

You could use the [Event API for screen width changes](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.Device.media), modify a view model in the event handler and bind the visible property to that view model as described in [Device Adaptation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d63a15e5eebb45cdada317bae5f45bc2).